# Yahoo CSV to HTML via PHP -- no longer works

Tags: php, html, csv, yahoo-finance

I was using a PHP script to convert Yahoo finance quotes to an HTML web page. But suddenly the web page stopped showing the data after a year of working perfectly and there were no code changes at all. Here is my code:

```
<table>
<tr>
<?php $fp = fopen ("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=VIP&f=l1c1p2rj1&e=.csv","r");
        $data = fgetcsv ($fp, 1000, ",") ?>
<td>Vimpel-Communications</td>
<td><?php echo $data[0] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $data[1] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $data[2] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $data[3] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $data[4] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $data[5] ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And here is a test page of the actual site: http://bricadr.com/test.php
Can anyone help or does anyone know what happened, or how I can fix this? Additionally, if anyone has a sever, can you see if this code works on your server? Perhaps my hosting company turned off some functionality that allowed this to previously work.

Thank you in advance!

Brian

Comment: Please define "stopped working". Errors? Wrong data? What else?

Comment: "Stopped working" meaning the data from the CVS file stopped displaying on the webpage where the PHP resides. Here is a sample page:
http://bricadr.com/test.php

Comment: As you can see from the above link, no data is showing on the page.

Comment: Have you tried any debugging? Like `var_dump($fp)` and `var_dump($data)` to see *what exactly* stopped working?

Comment: I have not used var_dump($fp) or var_dump($data) to see what stopped working. How can I do this, and what will it tell me?

Comment: It will tell you the contents of these variables so we can get some actual facts to base our debugging on instead of just guessing.

Comment: I have contacted my hosting company to see if they have disabled anything. As I mentioned earlier, the code has not changed. If anyone has a server, can you grab the code above and see if it works on your end?

Comment: Downvoted because this isn't clear and not in the form of a question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**: Tested it on my server. When not parsed, commented in the HTML is a notice of a 301 redirect. The new page is "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=VIP&f=l1c1p2rj1&e=.csv", simply change your URL. I've updated my below code if you would like to use it.

Anyway, here's a little effient-etized version of your code, using cURL because it is [much faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555523/file-get-contents-vs-curl-what-has-better-performance) than fopen. I also used explode because for some reason the cvs function was not working on my server.

```
$curl=curl_init();
curl_setopt ($curl,CURLOPT_URL,"http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=VIP&f=l1c1p2rj1&e=.csv");
curl_setopt ($curl,CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
ob_start();
curl_exec ($curl);
curl_close ($curl);
$data=ob_get_clean();
$data=explode(",",$data);
$data=str_replace('"','',$data);
foreach ($data as $results)
  echo "<td>$results</td>";
```

Working [here](http://connorpeet.com/betawebs/2012/cvs/).

Comment: Hi, thanks! But this URL is valid, it does download a CSV file when I enter it into my browser address bar. Did it not work for you?

Comment: I found your issue! Updated my post.

Comment: Hi Connor, Nice, that works in your script, BUT even with the updated URL my script still doesn't work. It's bizarre. The test page has your script for the first line, and mine with the updated URL for the rest: http://bricadr.com/test.php

Comment: Connor, all lines, or just the first line? The first line is your script, the rest are my old script with the updated URLs.

Comment: Just the first line. I linked the word "fine" to a screenshot.

Comment: Thanks Connor, I finally got my site working again: [My Working Site](http://bricadr.com/brazil_adr.php). 
I did notice that the "%" column has the quotes around the data provide. By enhancing the above PHP script, how could we get ride of those quotes? Ex: "+3.95%" becomes +3.95%

Comment: Just use a string replace on the data: `$data=str_replace($data,'"','')` I've updated the above.

Comment: Hi Connor, I think there is a small issue, because this broke the whole script, can you please update the "Working here" link to see what broke the code?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I had just mixed up arguments. Updated code and "Working Here"

Comment: Thanks Connor, that worked beautifully. Why are people giving this question "-3" when the question was fully answered, and how can I give you "+1" or more? This worked well!

Comment: No problem! You can click the arrow pointing up to the left of my post. When you hover over the that area, an outline of a check appears. If you click that, the answer will be marked as "correct".