# PHP: How can I eliminate quotes around output from CSV file?

Tags: php, csv

This code:

```
<?php $curl=curl_init();
curl_setopt ($curl,CURLOPT_URL,"http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=XIN&f=l1c1p2rj1y&e=.csv");
curl_setopt ($curl,CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
ob_start();
curl_exec ($curl);
curl_close ($curl);
$data=ob_get_clean();
$data = explode(",",$data);
foreach ($data as $results)
echo "<td>$results</td>";
?>
```

yields these results in my browser: 2.80    +0.02   "+0.72%"    1.85    204.2M  1.44

How can I have this PHP code above eliminate the quotations around the "+0.72%" so the end result is just: 0.72% ?

Comment: Use a real CSV reader. If the field starts with a `"` then it needs to be processed specialy. (In this case perhaps the generator considered "%" special?)

Answer (score 5):

Use [`fopen`](http://php.net/fopen) and [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/fgetcsv) to read the csv data, instead of exploding the lines yourself

EDIT:

In case you're dealing with a string that you already obtained with `curl`,
You can parse a **line** of csv data by using [`str_getcsv`](http://php.net/str_getcsv) like this:

```
$values = str_getcsv($line);
```

Note that it only works on a single line of input, so if your input has multiple lines, you need to explode it by newline first...

Comment: fopen stopped working, so I switched to curl, and it turns out curl is  a lot fast. I need to modify the above code as per my question. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Well, if you're already working with strings, you can apply [`str_getcsv`](http://php.net/str_getcsv) on each line to parse it according to csv rules...

Comment: Again, fopen stopped working with Yahoo finance. See [my earlier post here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646853/yahoo-csv-to-html-via-php-no-longer-works). So I need to modify the above code.

Comment: @brianjohnson i did not mention `fopen` in my comment.. `str_getcsv` works on a string (single line of csv file contents)...

Comment: Poncha, I'm not how to use str_getcsv. Can you please show an example so that it will get rid of the quote?

Comment: @brianjohnson added str_getcsv usage example in the answer. use that instead of `explode(",", $data);`